# Software design guidance needed (Android Library Project)

Tags: android, design-patterns, shared-libraries

- I have an App with my main Activity ("MainActivity")
- I have a View in a "Android Project Library". I would like to use this view in several Apps, thats why I added this view in a library.
- I can use the view from my App

But now comes the problem.

I would like to interact with my Apps MainActivity from my view.

If the view would be in the app insteed of library I would simply call...

```
(MainActivity)context.myfunction()
```

... in my view.

But in case of the library, my view doesn't know about the MainActivity, because its out of the project-scope.

How can I interact with the Activity from my view, which is placed in a library ? Any hints ?

Comment: What is wrong with this question. Why -2. Please argue, why you downvoted.

Comment: Probably for over-tagging? This is not really a "design pattern" question; more of a "how do a solve this specific android problem".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good solution, but I post it here. It will probably help others.

I created an Interface in my Library Project :

```
public interface InteractActivity {
    public void interact(String sCommand, List<Object> objects);
}
```

I implemented the Interface on my Activity :

```
@Override
    public void interact(String sCommand, List<Object> objects) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(sCommand.equals("mycommand")){
            do something ...
        }
    }
```

Then I simply call the method from my view (which is in my library Project):

```
((InteractActivity) context).interact("mycommand",myparameters);
```